# What is the most efficient way of condensing a large table in Python

Tags: python, data-structures

I need to condense some repeated field values in a cell

[image]

SFN numbers will be unique and related values will be condensed in a cell. For instance, I will create a single row for 1008-12 and PermitNo will be [3245, 3246], Elevation will be [1100, 1000], Year will be [2016, 2014] so on. I want only unique values per SFN but in the respective order.

The best idea I came up with creating dictionaries for each field to be condensed and go through rows with for loop then write the dictionaries back into a new table.

Is that a good way to do it? Is there a better way to do this such as object collection, nods etc? I mean space and time by efficiency. I have 1 million+ rows. I think I am fine with memory but it takes some time.

Comment: Your dict approach is basically what a relational database does with joins; it is a good approach.

If you're already using pandas you can achieve what you're trying to do with the `group by` methods

Depending on how your getting your data (sql query?) you can modify the query to perform the aggregations natively

Comment: What kind of "efficiency" are you looking for ?

Comment: @Amadeus, can you check if [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69437346/16343464) works for you? If this isn't what you want, please describe more explicitly your goal and provide example input/output **as text**.

Comment: How do you acquire and parse these data? The empty PermitNo cell for SFN 1008-16 is intriguing. Perhaps it's a file with fixed-width columns

Comment: You have edited your question to say "I want only unique values per SFN but in the respective order". Do you mean you want values (such as PermitNo) in numerical order or in the order in which they were observed?

Comment: Without knowing your domain, I'd caution you about this type of aggregation. In my experience doing what you're doing has almost always led to confusion. You end up with several arrays of data that are related but hard to read/understand and outputs from these types of things often end up needing to be reconstituted down the road by somebody else.

For instance, add another row: `1008-17, 8802, 45, 760, 2011, 16` the thickness and elevation cannot be meaningfully reconstituted from `1008-17, 8802, {25, 35, 45}, {750, 760}, {2011, 2013}, 16`

Comment: @Schalton I know what you mean relations get lost. We have another mechanism relating all fields in a meaningful way. However, I think you are right it is better to keep things organized. I might create lists instead of sets. I will keep the lists at the same length so all index values will be synchronized.  Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can aggregate using python sets:

```
df.groupby('col1', as_index=False).agg(set)
```

Here is a dummy example as you didn't provide the dataset as text:

input:

```
  col1 col2  col3
0    A    a     0
1    A    b     1
2    A    a     2
3    B    b     1
4    B    a     2
5    B    d     1
6    C    a     0
7    C    c     1
8    C    b     0
```

output:

```
  col1       col2       col3
0    A     {b, a}  {0, 1, 2}
1    B  {d, b, a}     {1, 2}
2    C  {b, a, c}     {0, 1}
```

Comment: unfortunately I'm not sure this approach will work; I think the set would need to be replaced with a list since it seems OP wants to be able to reconstruct the table from the output

Comment: @Schalton is this how you understand it? I had the feeling OP wants to get the unique values. Of course if order and matches are important, then sets aren't appropriate

Comment: Absolutely fair point -- the wording of the question is a bit subjective; I didn't downvote, but thought I'd call it out

Comment: @Schalton no worries, that was a relevant comment, just hard to know without more details from OP

Comment: It worked better than my method and yes I wanted unique  values  in the respective order for condensed values

Comment: @Amadeus sets are unordered! so it might not be exactly what you want, then you might need to use `list` (and drop duplicates before if any). Let me know if you need more details

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely going to want to use pandas to do this, as this is what it is the kind of thing it's built for.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("/path/to/your/data.csv")
df = df.groupby('SFN').agg(set).reset_index()
```

I think this should work for your example, but as you didn't provide data I haven't tested it.

Comment: mozway already provided this answer (a full 6 minutes before you) if you think his answer can be improved perhaps add a comment instead of a [mostly] duplicate answer

Comment: If the data is like the image shown in the question, read_csv() won't cope with it